In Nuxt 3 application how to disable auto-imports for server folder?
You can disable all auto-imports altogether, is there a way to disable auto-importing only from server/utils folder?
I've played around with nitro.imports.imports but to no avail.

Write the imports as if there were none to solve the issue, no need for any config so far.

It should be like :
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    //other configs
    nitro: {
        imports: {
            autoImport: false,
        },
    },
})

